# Why is my laravel 5.1.* project not working properly on XAMPP linux

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-5.1

I have been working on two laravel 5.1.* projects. I have been using the built-in server and running the projects like so:

```
php artisan serve
http://localhost:8000
```

Everything has been working perfectly but now I have copied both projects and place in my htdocs directory and accessing them like so:

Project one: `http://localhost/lara_rocks1/public/`

This works when I simply navigate across pages but no authentication and registration function works. I use the the traits shipped with laravel to implement auth. For example, when I click login, logout etc, the page just refreshes and nothing happens. What can be the problem?

Project two: `http://localhost/the_future/public/auth/login`

For this case, just a blank page is shown. What are my missing out?

Below is the content of my .htaccess file in public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

Had a same problem like yours in project 2. For me storage folder did not have write permition use:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

For project one they file

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth
```

Here are all paths and redirects for implemented register,login,logout functions in laravel

Hope it helps

Comment: The storage directory was actually the problem. I did something slightly different from your answer. Rather than give storage a 777 which I think is generally not advisable for security reasons, I made my server owner of the directory like so  `sudo chown -R daemon storage/`. Thanks for your input @SitaReturn. Moving forward right now.